# using NtCreateSection from ntdll.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I was just trying to use NtCreateSection in my code and the information at [this link](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Section/NtCreateSection.html) states the requirement as ntdll.lib. As Im using VS2010, I went to Projects > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies and added ntdll.lib.

However, on building the solution I get an error `error C3861: 'NtCreateSection': identifier not found`. I'm curious about why this happens.

A workaround I'm considering is getting a handle to ntdll using LoadLibrary and getting a handle to NtCreateSection using GetProcAddress; however Im just curious about why the earlier method did not work out.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your headers, or library versions, offer that function? It's very possible the headers don't have it, or some versions of the system don't export it. It is marked as sooper seecret, which typically also means not for users/doesn't follow spec. In other news, that site seems like it could be an interesting read.

Comment: Aren't `NtXxx` **kernel**-mode functions?

Comment: @moshbear Unless Im much mistaken, functions that start with Nt and Zw are parts of the native api(ntdll.dll, which is usermode callers and ntoskrnl.exe, the kernel mode callers). In this case the function is from ntdll.dll, hence a usermode caller, I believe.

Comment: Native API was what I meant. It's been a while since I've done low-level Win32. In any case, you likely need WDK headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps of interest is the actual documentation of the function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556473(v=vs.85).aspx

This points you to a ZwCreateSection function, which notes that NtCreateSection is the name to be used for user-mode calls to this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566428(vr85).aspx

In the standard header/library reference in the *actual* documentation, it says `Wdm.h` is the header to be included. I would recommend checking that file for the function(s), and proceeding from there. The docs for both functions, and the guide pages linked from them, also seem to have some info on things.